# Find contacts with multiple relationships of same type

Tags: api, php

We try to gather total number of users of same Relationship Type but different number of Relationships (mean, user can be a Member of no / 1 / 2 3 .. etc. Organisations).

Here's a code we use:

```
$start = microtime(true);
$total_count = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getcount', array(
 'return' => "id",
  'contact_type' => "Individual",
  'is_deleted' => 0,
      ));
  $result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
    'sequential' => 1,
    'return' => "id",
    'contact_type' => "Individual",
    'is_deleted' => 0,
    'options' => array(
       'limit' => $total_count, 
       ),
      'api.Relationship.getcount' => array(
        'is_active' => 1,
        'relationship_type_id' => 4,
)));

foreach ($result['values'] as $r) {
  $relscount[] = $r['api.Relationship.getcount']; 
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_count_values($relscount));
echo '</pre>';
 $time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
  echo 'Time spent: ' . $time_elapsed_secs . '<br>';

# Records: Time #
# 1000: 4.2179801464081
# 5000: 23.655788183212
# 15000: 74.082838058472
```

There is one tiny issue though: we've around 100K Contacts in a DB and we haven't been able to find out how much time it takes to count 'em all..

The most obvious solution seems to be one of array traversing techniques involving for/foreach/while and "limit" + "offset". Just wondering, what is  a better/smarter move, if exists?

**UPD**

Code which uses "getcount" is even slower:

```
$start = microtime(true);
 $result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'debug' => 1,
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "id",
  'contact_type' => "Individual",
  'is_deleted' => 0,
  'api.Relationship.getcount' => array(
    'contact_id_a' => "\$value.id", 
    'relationship_type_id' => 4
  ),
  'options' => array('limit' => 15000),
 ));

 foreach ($result['values'] as $r) {
   $relscount[] = $r['api.Relationship.getcount']; 
 }

 echo '<pre>';
   print_r(array_count_values($relscount));
 echo '</pre>';


$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
  echo 'Time spent: ' . $time_elapsed_secs . '<br>'; 

  # Records: Time #
  # 15000: 101.00403809547
```